# how can I pass data that is calculated in one component to another component on different page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one component in which I calculate price based on model and extras that go with it. it looks like this:

product.jsx:

```
  const name = productData.name;
  
  const modelPrice = productData.modelPrice; {/*Array that must contain: [key: number, model: string, price: number] */}
  
 

  {/*NewExtras START */}
  const extrasList = productData.extras; {/*Array that must contain: [ key: number, name: string, price: number, active: boolean (default: false) ] */}

  const [extrasListP, setExtrasListP] = useState(extrasList);

  const toggleExtras = (extra) => {
    const updatedExtrasList = extrasListP.map((ex) => {
      extra.name === ex.name ? ex.active = !ex.active : ex.active = ex.active;
      return ex;
    });
    setExtrasListP(updatedExtrasList);
  }; 

  const activeExtras = extrasListP.filter((extra) => {
    return extra.active;
  });

  const aExtrasList = activeExtras.map((extra) => {
    return (
      <div key={extra.key}>{extra.name},&nbsp;</div>
    );
  })

  const sumExtras = activeExtras.reduce((previousValue, object) => {
    return previousValue + object.price;
  }, 0);


  {/*NewExtras END */}

  const [quantity, setQuantity] = useState(1);
  
  {/*Model variables START */}
  
  const [activeModel, setActiveModel] = useState(modelPrice[0].model);
  const [activePrice, setActivePrice] = useState(modelPrice[0].price);
  
  const modelPriceList = modelPrice.map((item) => {
    return (
      <div
      key = {item.key}
      className={ activePrice === item.price ? styles.activeModelItem : styles.modelItem}
      onClick={() => {setActiveModel(item.model); setActivePrice(item.price)}}
      >
        | {item.model} |
      </div>
    );
  });
  
  {/*Model variables END */}
  
  const [buttonText, setButtonText] = useState("Dodaj u korpu");

  const finalPrice = (activePrice + sumExtras) * quantity;

  const [korpa, setKorpa] = useState([]);
  
  const toSend = <>proizvod: {name} - Model: {activeModel} - Dodatno: - {aExtrasList} - Količina: {quantity} - Ukupno: {finalPrice}</>;
```

I want to create component called Cart.jsx to which I will send: **toSend** variable.
I also want it to stay chached so it stays when user refreshes page.

I was searching the internet for week and a half now and cant seem to find suitable answer for my situation. I hope that somebody will at least point me at right direction.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is a "page" in your application? *What* is the data and *where* are you trying to send it? Please edit the post to include all relevant code you are working with as part of a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass data from one page to another page, then these are the ways:

1. pass data via state while routing

```
// react route v5
history.push("path", {state: yourdata})
// react router v6
navigate("path", {state: yourdata})
```

2. Pass data in query string while routing

```
const queryString = `data=${JSON.stringify(yourdata)}`;
// attach above query in route path like this:
// react route v5
history.push(`path?${queryString}`, {state: yourdata})
// react router v6
navigate(`path?${queryString}`, {state: yourdata})
```

3. Set data in local storage or session storage and access on next page.

```
const stringifyData = JSON.stringify(yourData);
localStorage.set("yourkey", stringifyData);

// Now access data on next page
JSON.parse(localStorage.get("yourKey"));
```

In your case, you want to persist data. So option 3 will suit your use case

Comment: thank you, third option solved my problem... :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do all of your calculations on the parent component and then assign that to a state hook. You can then pass that as props to the Cart.jsx component. Whenever you run your function to add to the total you can update a total state, then when you want to pass it to the cart you can via props.

```
const [total, setTotal] = useState(0);

const addTotalSum = () => {
    // Logic here for getting the total.
    setTotal(); // Set the returned total value here
}
...
<Cart totalVal={total} /> // Pass total into Cart component as props and then access it in the Cart with props.totalVal
```